# Derivation of function from $\mathbb{R}^6$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^6\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Why does the following equality holds:

$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}{f(x_1-t,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$$

I think that is the chain rule, but I am confused if i have to use it. Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You certainly don't *have* to use the chain rule, in the sense that you can derive this particular case of it from scratch --- which might be your preference if you never expect to need the chain rule again for anything else, ever.  But with just slightly more work, you can get the full generality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly a chain rule. But to be clear note that:
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}{f(x_1-t,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)}=-\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6).$$

You take the derivative with respect to the 'first variable slot' regardless of what is sitting in it ($x_1-t$ in this case), then you do the chain rule and multiply by the derivative of what is sitting in the first variable slot ($-1$ in this case).

Comment: If you like the answer, you could "upvote it" and "select it with the check mark". Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**
Use chain rule. set $u_1=x_1-t$ and $u_i=x_i\qquad i=2,...,6$
$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}{f(u_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)}=\sum_1^6\frac{\partial}{\partial u_i}|_{u_1=x_1}{f(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6)}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$$